# Set a Target to display URL on a frame

Tags: php, html

I have a frameset top, left, main.  When I click a link on the left, the page should display in the main frame but my code does not work.  it opened into a new page

The php is loading an XML which works, parse into a table cell which work and converting to URL also works, just the target to display does not.

Can someone help me to correct it?

---frame.html----

```
<frame name="main" src="main.html" id="main" marginwidth="10" marginheight="10" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" noresize>
```

----menu.php----

```
echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr0\" target=\"main\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
```

Many thanks.

Comment: The code in `menu.php` is probably broken. Is `$arr0` a variable? a string? Did you want to to **use** it or just print it as a string?

Comment: Hi, $arr0 =   $arr0 = "arr0.php";.  The URL link works but the display is always on a new page.  The problem is since I am using frameset, I want to display the URL on my right frame.  The arr0.php is on the same web folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks.  I got the answer.  I need to change $arr0 = "full URL string";  It works when I set target="main".